# Custom Dict Dropping Keys When Cast

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I have a custom class that inherit from dict (shown below) and when I cast the object to a dict, it drops the key called 'type'.  Is there any reason why this is happening?

I expect the following results:

> > > dm = Parameter()
> > >
> > > print(dict(dm))
> > >
> > > {'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item', 'title': 'foo'}

What I end up getting is:

> > > {'tags': 'bar', 'title': 'foo'}

The `self._map` contains the 'type' key/value pair, so I don't know what could be the problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
class ItemParameter(dict):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 title,
                 tags):
        super(ItemParameter, self).__init__(title=title, tags=tags)
        self._map = {}
        self._allowed_keys = {'type':'type',
                              'title': 'title',
                              'tags':'tags',
                              'thumbnail': 'thumbnail',
                              'thumbnailurl': 'thumbnailurl',
                              'metadata': 'metadata',
                              'type_keywords' : 'typeKeywords',
                              'description': 'description',
                              'snippet' : 'snippet'}
        self['type'] = "Item"
        self['title'] = title
        self['tags'] = tags

    def __iter__(self):
        for k, v in self.items():
            yield k, v

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k in self._allowed_keys:
            self._map[self._allowed_keys[k]] = v

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k in self._map:
            return self._map[k]
        elif k in self._allowed_keys and \
             self._allowed_keys[k] in self._map:
            return self._map[self._allowed_keys[k]]

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if k in {'_map','_dynamic', '_allowed_keys',
                 '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            super(ItemParameter, self).__setattr__(k,v)
        else:
            if k in self._allowed_keys.keys():
                self._map[self._allowed_keys[k]] = v

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        if k == {'_map','_dynamic', '_allowed_keys',
                 '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            super(ItemParameter, self).__getattr__(k)
        else:
            if k in self._allowed_keys.keys() and \
               self._allowed_keys[k] in self._map:
                return self._map[self._allowed_keys[k]]
    def __delattr__(self, key):
        return self._map.__delitem__(key)
    def __contains__(self, k):
        return self._map.__contains__(k)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._map)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
    def items(self):
        return self._map.items()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ShadowRanger mentions, it's bad design to duplicate the `dict` data in the `._map` attribute, and you're generally much better off not subclassing the built-in types.

I've reduced your code down to the bare minimum that reproduces this "bug", and I'm still not totally sure why it behaves *exactly* like it does, but we can fix the bug by making sure that `__setitem__` adds the new item to `self` as well as to `self._map`. For example:

```
def __setitem__(self, k, v):
    if k in self._allowed_keys:
        k = self._allowed_keys[k]
        self._map[k] = v
        super(ItemParameter, self).__setitem__(k, v)
```

---

Here's a new version of your class that does what I think you want. It uses the Python 3 version of `super()` which has a zero args form.

```
class ItemParameter(dict):
    allowed = {
        'type':'type',
        'title': 'title',
        'tags':'tags',
        'thumbnail': 'thumbnail',
        'thumbnailurl': 'thumbnailurl',
        'metadata': 'metadata',
        'type_keywords' : 'typeKeywords',
        'description': 'description',
        'snippet' : 'snippet',
    }

    def __init__(self, title, tags):
        super().__init__(title=title, tags=tags)
        self['type'] = "Item"

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k in ItemParameter.allowed:
            k = ItemParameter.allowed[k]
            super().__setitem__(k, v)

    def update(self, other):
        for k, v in other.items():
            self[k] = v

# test

p = ItemParameter(title='foo', tags='bar')
for t in p:
    print(t)
print(p)
print(p.copy())
print(dict(p))
p['type_keywords'] = 'some thing'
print(p)
p['bad'] = 'other thing'
print(p)
p.update({'a':1, 'b':2, 'metadata': 3})
print(p)
```

**output**

```
title
tags
type
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item'}
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item'}
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item'}
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item', 'typeKeywords': 'some thing'}
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item', 'typeKeywords': 'some thing'}
{'title': 'foo', 'tags': 'bar', 'type': 'Item', 'typeKeywords': 'some thing', 'metadata': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response!

Answer (score 1):

You've got two completely different `dict`s here; the one that's implicitly part of your own object's structure (because you inherit from `dict`) and `_map`. The two keys you're seeing are the ones you set by calling the superclass `__init__` (first line in your initializer) which delegates to `update` (which you also didn't override), while the `dict` constructor you're using to `print` is ignoring them.

In general, it's a bad idea to try to inherit from `dict` itself while changing meaningful behaviors, because it's easy to miss an important code path and not get the results you expect. For example, in this case, I believe the handling code is calling your classes's `keys` method, which you didn't override, so it's getting `keys` from the superclass implementation, which bypasses your custom code.

Even if you did override it, there are occasional fast paths scattered around the code that can end up bypassing your custom code for performance boosts, reading the `dict` components of your subclass directly (without seeing `_map` or your custom `__[gs]etitem__` overrides at all).

I'd suggest looking at inheriting from `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, so you're not a true `dict`, but it's more intuitive what methods require overriding and how you must do it.

If you must be a `dict` subclass, operate on yourself directly, not a `_map` member, so you'll be usable as a `dict` in the first place. Use `super()` to call parent methods, e.g. replacing:

```
def __setitem__(self, k, v):
    if k in self._allowed_keys:
        self._map[self._allowed_keys[k]] = v
```

with:

```
def __setitem__(self, k, v):
    if k in self._allowed_keys:
        super().__setitem__(self._allowed_keys[k], v)
```

which will alter the `dict` structure you inherited from, not an unrelated attribute that happens to be a `dict` too.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying about the `._map` attribute, and using `collections` instead of subclassing `dict`. However, I don't think "I believe the handling code is calling your classes's keys method, which you didn't override, so it's getting keys from the superclass implementation, which bypasses your custom code" is true. This "bug" still occurs if we add: `def keys(self): return self._map.keys()`. But it doesn't occur if we convert the `ItemParameter` instance to a list or tuple (even without the new `keys` method), so I'm puzzled as to what's the actual cause.

Comment: Also, if we print the `._map` attribute, it has all the expected items. But I just noticed that calling `.copy()` returns the reduced dictionary, and we still get the original bug if I add `def copy(self): return self._map.copy()`.

Comment: @shadowranger Thank you for the information.  I want to ensure that only certain keys get placed into the dictionary, and on cast, I only want the _allowed_keys to be in the dictionary that was my reasoning for having the ```self._map```